# Django form does not appear

Tags: django, forms, django-forms, django-cms

I'm working with building a webpage with a form using Django's Form class.  I've included some sample code snippets but my problem is that I've followed the Django docs and the tutorial in Djangobook but can't get my Form to actually display on the page.

**forms.py**

```
from django import forms

class ResearchForm(forms.Form):
    fam_choices = ...
    spec_choices = ...
    family = forms.ChoiceField(choices=fam_choices, required=True)
    species = forms.ChoiceField(choices=spec_choices, required=True)
```

**views.py**

```
from django.http import HttpResponse, HttpResponseRedirect, Http404
from django.shortcuts import render
from mysite.forms import ResearchForm

...

def research(request):
    if request.method == 'GET': 
        form = ResearchForm(request.GET)
        if form.is_valid():
            f = form.cleaned_data['family']
            s = form.cleaned_data['species']
            return render(request, 'thankyou.html', {})
    else: 
         form = ResearchForm() # an unbound form
    return render(request, "research.html", {'form':form})
```

**research.html**

```
...
<form action="/research/" method="get" name="researchform">
   {{ form.as_p}}
   <button>Submit</button>
</form>
...
```

Only the button appears on the webpage, not the `select` tags that `ChoiceField` should render.

**EDIT:**

I edited my `views.py` to this:

```
def research(request):
    form = ResearchForm(request.GET)
    if form.is_valid():
        return render(request, 'thankyou.html', {})
    else: 
        form = ResearchForm()
        return render(request, 'research.html', {'form':form})
```

**EDIT 2:**

**urls.py**

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    url(r'^', include('cms.urls')),
)

if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns = patterns('',
        (r'^' + settings.MEDIA_URL.lstrip('/'), include('appmedia.urls')),
    ) + urlpatterns
```

Answer (score 2):

When you first render the page the first condition will be called:

```
if request.method == 'GET':
```

and because form is not valid, it never gets passed anywhere, so the `form` variable is empty.

Instead of `GET` there should be `POST` in both places.

```
if request.method == 'POST': 
    form = ResearchForm(request.POST)
```

Comment: thanks for your reply.  I changed my code to read `POST` like you described.  The form tag's attribute is still `GET`.  Then, I restarted my Apache and refreshed the page but still no form being displayed.  Any other suggestions?

Comment: yea I tried that too but that didn't work either.  Is there no way to do GET requests with Django forms?  Since it's a POST request, I added `{% csrf_token %}` which is fine by me.  I can click the submit button and get the appropriate page...it's the fact that the form itself is not even showing up that's what's bothering me.

Comment: @noblerare The form should display either case, did you try django-debug-toolbar, to see if the form object exists in the template context? It's difficult to say what's wrong, since the code with my suggestion should work. Have you tried rendering the unbound form only (without the condition)? Maybe it's an Apache issue, try running the project with dev server..

Comment: The form should be displayed regardless of whether or not the `action` attribute of the `form` tag is set, right?  I have: `<form action="" method="POST">` right now and still no form is displayed.  But now, I am a bit confused, if the `research` function in `views.py` is only called when I click the button, how does Django know what data to put in the `{{ form.as_p }}` placeholder without setting that context variable?

Answer (score 0):

You should not check the method, but only the validity of the form. Something like:

```
def research(request):
    form = ResearchForm(request.GET)
    if form.is_valid():
        f = form.cleaned_data['family']
        s = form.cleaned_data['species']
        return render(request, 'thankyou.html', {})
    else: 
        form = ResearchForm() # an unbound form
        return render(request, "research.html", {'form':form})
```

That way, if the GET request contains valid form data the thank-you page is displayed, and if not, the form is rendered.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.  I tried that but nothing so far. Something weird is going on.  On my `research.html` page, no form is displayed.  Then, when I click the Submit button, it doesn't seem to be calling the `research` function in `views.py` but rather trying to visit the `/research` webpage which doesn't exist.  Is there something wrong in my HTML?

Comment: In your HTML, you'd better use the [URL tag](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#url) for the action instead of `/research`, because that is exactly where you're pointing the form to. (Update: could you post your `urls.py`too?)

Comment: @LaundroMat, I updated my question with the `urls.py`.  I also added: `{% url "mysite.views.research %}` in the `action` attribute of the `form` tag and now I get a  NoReverseMatch error.

Comment: That's because there is no url configured for the research view. You should add `url(r'^research/', research, name="research")` and `from mysite.views import research`

Comment: @LaundroMat: Thanks for your reply. Yes, that does work but I'm wondering if that's "kosher."  Because I have a CMS, should I just be adding the pages to the `urls.py` or creating them in the CMS admin?

Comment: That I can't help you with, I'm sorry. I'd have a look at the CMS documentation and check whether it is supposed to create its own URL scheme based on what you're doing in the admin, or whether "tinkering" is acceptable.