# Django forms - rendering form and redirecting

Tags: django, python-2.7, django-forms, http-post

I am trying to create an 'add user' feature which will simply add the user you've selected from a dropdown as your connection. I am using ModelChoiceField from Django Forms so that I may get the existing users from my User model in the dropdown.

**forms.py**

```
from django import forms
from django.contrib.auth.models import User


class NetworkForm(forms.Form):
    user_id = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=User.objects.all(), label='',
                                       widget=forms.Select(attrs={'class': 'all_users'}))
```

**views.py**

```
@login_required
def index(request):
    user_list = User.objects.exclude(username=request.user)
    return render(request, 'chat/index.html', {'user_list': user_list})
```

> For now I am just printing the form to see output

```
@login_required
def add_user(request):
    form = NetworkForm()
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = NetworkForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            print form 
            return redirect(request.META['HTTP_REFERER'])

    errors = form.errors or None

    return render(request, 'chat/index.html', {
        'form': form,
        'errors': errors,
    })
```

**index.html**

```html
<div class="row">
<form action="{% url 'chat:add_user' %}" method="post">
{% csrf_token %}
{{ form.as_p }}
<button class="btn btn-warning" value="{{ user_id }}" style="float: left;">Submit</button>
</form>
</div>
```

**urls.py**

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.index, name='index'),
    url(r'^add_user/$', views.add_user, name='add_user'),]
```

The way it is being rendered currently is: I have my main index page where I don't see any dropdown, i.e.,
[image]

When I click on the submit button, it moves me to index/add_user, where I get a dropdown with user (with a warning "this field is required) and a submit button again.
[image]

Finally, when I choose a user in this new page and hit submit, finally the form is printed, which I want ultimately.[image]

***What I would want it, have the complete form with dropdown in the index page itself and remain there when I submit the form.*** I will then hook that to show user the users they have added beneath that form itself ('print' is just for debugging purpose - not a good way I've heard though).
I understand the post request will have to go to add_user page and I can redirect back from that. I have tried various alternatives for the past 6 hours, nothing works yet. Apologies for a long one, giving out information as much as possible. Thanks very much guys. You are awesome.

**Edit**
Have been now rendering the form in index page (suggestion from @fazil-zaid ), but the issue remains as in only 'submit' button appears on index initially, unless when I hit submit after which the dropdown and submit appears. Again, on clicking the second time, the form is submitted.

**Edit-2**
I am thinking that:

```
<form action="{% url 'chat:index' %}" method="post">{% csrf_token %}
{{ form.as_p }}
    <button class="btn btn-warning" value="{{ user_id }}" style="float: left;">Submit</button>
</form>
```

this might be where the problem is, as per current logic unless user takes form's action, i.e., clicks the button {{ form.as_p }} will not appear. Then I tried:

```
{{ form.as_p }}
<form action="{% url 'chat:index' %}" method="post">{% csrf_token %}
    <button class="btn btn-warning" value="{{ user_id }}" style="float: left;">Submit</button>
</form>
```

**Doesn't work still**. POST request doesn't send any data (understandably so).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solution**:
When the page is called in the first instance using GET, the form is not valid as it seeks a POST method. Hence, all the method need to be changed to POST in the view, i.e.,

```
@login_required
def index(request):
    user_list = User.objects.exclude(username=request.user)
    form = NetworkForm()
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = NetworkForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            print form.data
            return redirect(request.META['HTTP_REFERER'])

    return render(request, 'chat/index.html', {
        'user_list': user_list,
        'form': form,
    })
```

Earlier, index was using a GET to render data to index page, and using a POST to use the form. Now, everything works fine. 
Special shout-out to [@fazil-zaid](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7256228/fazil-zaid) for the heads-up since you mentioned to include everything in the index view itself, rather than making a separate view for form. Your code pointed that out in a way in addition to [Stack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21391510/django-form-does-not-appear) here.

Comment: @fazil-zaid Not sure whether I mark my answer as the answer or yours? Yours was definitely a big pointer. You seem to be a veteran stacker, tell me what the norms is please.

Comment: For the lack of reply from fazil, I will make my answer the answer, user are advised to look at fazil's and mine together as combined two makes the final answer.

Answer (score 1):

If you want the form to be in the index page, then you could include it in the index view itself.

```
def index(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = NetworkForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            #do what you wanna do
            #with the form data.
    else:
        form = NetworkForm()
    render(request, 'chat/index.html', { 'form': form})
```

In the template,

```
<div class="row"> 
<form action="" method="post"> 
{% csrf_token %} 
{{ form.as_p }} 
<button class="btn btn-warning" value="{{ user_id }}" style="float: left;">Submit</button> 
</form> 
</div>
```

You are not rendering another template, but the same 'index.html'. Then, multiple view for that is just redundant. Index page could contain the form and render itself. From what I understand, there's no need of redirections.

There's no need of add_user view if you're showing the form in the index page itself.

For your issue, try changing the "class" attribute of the form fields, maybe something like this,

```
class NetworkForm(forms.Form):
    user_id = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=User.objects.all(), widget=forms.Select(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}))
```

Comment: Thanks man. Yes, this is achievable and I did it that way.
Now what is happening is:
1. index page shows only the submit button.
2. Click on submit, the page remains the same but now the dropdown appears along with submit button.
3. Click on submit again and then only the form data is transmitted.
How to remove the step 1 from the picture is what the ultimate issue.

_+1 for hint towards removing additional url._

Comment: Updated the answer

Comment: Changed the class as per your suggestion, not working still. 
I added the earlier class, namely 'all_users' just to get proper CSS done with form elements.

Comment: What I was thinking was the way it is right now, unless the user does the form action in:
                <form action="{% url 'chat:index' %}" method="post">{% csrf_token %}
                    {{ form.as_p }}
                    <button class="btn btn-warning" value="{{ user_id }}" style="float: left;">Submit</button>
                </form> form will not appear as it is bound by that logic. But then I tried {{ form.as_p }} above the <form></form> tags. Still dropdown doesn't display.